# XSLT template match for parenthesis

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to XSLT and need your help on a simple xslt transformation-

I have below xml snippet-

```
<body>
<p class="C19Centre">1 January 2020(<a href="#Footnote*" name="Footref*">*</a>)
</p></body>
```

and am doing below xslt transformation for footnotes.

```
<xsl:template match="a[matches(@href,'#Footnote*') and matches(@name,'Footref*')]">
        <xsl:variable name="foot_note_num" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="foot_ref" select="concat('#Footref',$foot_note_num)"/>
        <fn><fnn><xsl:value-of select="$foot_note_num" /></fnn>
            <fnt>
                <xsl:for-each select="$judgment/p[matches(@class,'C*ootnote*')]/a[@href=$foot_ref]/(parent::node())">
                    <xsl:for-each select="node()[not(self::a)]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', ' '))"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fnt>
        </fn>
    </xsl:template>
```

And This is my current output which is as expected-

```
<p>1 January 2020(<fn>
           <fnn>*</fnn>
           <fnt>Language of the case: English.</fnt>
        </fn>)</p>
```

Here, I also want to remove the parenthesis () at the start and end of `<fn>` tag . How can I achieve that?
I tried to include '(' in my template match, but it gives a bad pattern error.

Comment: Note that `matches()` expects a *regex*, not a substring. I believe you forgot to escape `'C*ootnote*'`, what you probably meant to write `'C\*ootnote\*'` (or maybe `'C.*ootnote.*'`, I can't tell). Double check your regex patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write two templates that deal with the special situations *"text node right before an `<a>`"* and *"text node right after an `<a>`"* and then leave it to `<xsl:apply-templates>` to use them:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="p" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[matches(@href, '#Footnote\*') and matches(@name,'Footref\*')]" mode="p">
  <fn>
    <fnn>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </fnn>
    <fnt>
      <!-- fetch footnote text -->
    </fnt>
  </fn>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::a] and following-sibling::node()[1][self::a]]" mode="p">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^[\n\s]*\)|\([\n\s]*$', '')" />
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::a]]" mode="p">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\([\n\s]*$', '')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::a]]" mode="p">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^[\n\s]*\)', '')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Here the template `mode` is to prevent that the template is used for *any* `text()` that happens to be in front of an `<a>`. An alternative would be to make the templates match `p/text()[...]` only.

The regular expressions leave all unrelated parantheses in place.

Result for

```
<body>
<p class="C19Centre">1 January 2020(<a href="#Footnote*" name="Footref*">*</a>
) also other text</p></body>
```

would be

```
<p>1 January 2020<fn>
      <fnn>*</fnn>
      <fnt/>
   </fn> also other text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! This worked for me. But, how are we getting opening '('  in following-sibling of <a> and ')' in preceding-sibling of </a> ?

Comment: @Vikas Oh, you mean when there are multiple footnotes one after another? I did not think of that, but a third template solves this easily. Added above.